# async_job patch in Kaoryia's gVim (windows)

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, async

Kaoryia's gVim [builds](http://www.kaoriya.net/software/vim/) for Win32/64 come with a number of extra, non-official patches enabled.

Some of them are pretty clear: `:set charspace=-1`, for example, will tighten the space between characters; `:set transparency=250` will do what its name implies.

But there is also this patch: [async job](https://bitbucket.org/koron/vim-kaoriya-patches/src/32dc7fa41a91/X008-async_job.diff), by Taro MURAOKA, briefly described in the source as:

```
job.c - Asynchronous job support
```

Does anyone know what exactly it does, with perhaps an example about its usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That patch job, defines a new VimL function `jobrun()`. But you better ask at that repository for a documentation.

Comment: I just saw that actually *that* patch isn't enabled, so ... it's probably not without issues.

Comment: well, if you need async, i suggest, looking into neovim